# SPFX 1.12 gulp serve-deprecated alternative

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, yeoman-generator

Recenlty i decided to update the spfx libs of my webparts project to the v1.12.1
I have followed the steps indicated in the official Microsoft documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.12.1

Now I realized that gulp serve has been replaced with: 'gulp serve-deprecated'. So Ive gone to the official documentation and I have read this:

> Local workbench is deprecated - This is the last release that will
> include support for the local workbench. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.12.1#deprecations-and-removed-items-in-this-release

So my question now is: how is supposed to work with web parts development now or in the future?

If i cant test my web parts with gulp serve how is supposed I can to test them?

Answer (score 1):

Below are requirement to run and test SPFx 1.12.1 webpart.

```
node version  v14.15.5

+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1-rc.3
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- npm@6.14.11
`-- yo@4.0.0
```

gulp serve will work with current release and with the next release.

local work bench will work with current SPFx version 1.12.1. In next release it won't be supported.

You can test your webpart in SharePoint workbench instead of local workbench.

You change the URL of local work bench in sever.json file so that gulp serve will open this URL always.

```
"initialPage": "https://Yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx"
```

Please accept the answer & upvote it if you are satisfied with answer.

Comment: Theres no a gulp serve command in the current release. Theres a gulp serve-deprecated instead. Thats why im asking what way is supposed to be followed in next releases to aproach the webpart development.
Thank u for your answer and for the way to test webparts under SP workbench.

Comment: If you run "gulp --tasks" command you will get gulp serve and gulp serve-deprecated both. please check.

Comment: Nope. Only serve-deprecated available. I did a workaround to make gulp serve available again:
`var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set('serve', result.get('serve-deprecated'));

  return result;
};`

Comment: Daniel, read through the release notes of 1.12.1 it explains how to bring back gulp serve (map it to the deprecated name). This is required to be able to run the gulp serve. As for the future - we don't know yet what would be replacing gulp serve... but I am assuming something similar that will only work with the online workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Note that https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.12.1 has **recently** been updated, indicating that you need to update your gulpfile.js to be able to run gulp serve